# An outgoing call cannot be made since the app is dispatching an input-synchronous call

Tags: c++, exception, com, mfc

I have a MFC application with a dialog that has an *edit control* for user input. When I set a value and click with the mouse outside the control on the dialog everything works fine and the viewer (other dialog inside the main dialog) updates correctly. When I set the value and click on the viewer the function

```
psink_interface->QueryInterface( 
                               IID_IConnectionPointContainer,           
                               (void**)&pIConnectionPointContainerTemp
                               );
```

returns an error HRESULT

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLYNP.png

and the program gets an exception

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvA7I.png

Can someone please help me with some guidance? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The exception code C000041D is _STATUS_FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION_.  Without seeing more code, I would suspect you've got a bug in a function you are calling.

Comment: The first error, "the outgoing call ...", is caused by trying to make an out-of-apartment COM call from inside a message handler for a message delivered by `SendMessage` (as opposed to `PostMessage`). For certain technical reasons, such calls are not allowed (they could lead to a deadlock). It appears that your "viewer" is communicating with some out-of-process COM server, and in particular tries to do so from a sent message handler.

Comment: The technical reason is that a thread calling `SendMessage` to a window on another thread (e.g. `[input_sync]` calls) may itself process non-queued messages only for the duration of the call.  So, if the second thread tries to call `PostMessage` on the first thread and wait for the message to be processed, it'll deadlock, since the first thread isn't processing queued messages.

Comment: More subtly, if the second thread posts (instead of sending) to a third thread, that third thread won't know that it's processing within an input sync call from the first thread, so it wouldn't know whether posting to it would deadlock or not.  So, going from input sync to just sync isn't allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the comments!
And how can I prevent this to happen? How can I make the click of the mouse to be treated as if I clicked on the main dialog when I'm modifying the edit control? (I don't know if this makes any sense)

Comment: I'm having the same issue 8 years later, except I'm already in an STA thread. I expect that I need to set a delegate to be executed after the input_sync has completed, but I don't know how I would know when that is. Using the main window's dispatcher doesn't seem to help. Did you ever figure this out, @cosmotel ?

Comment: I ended up resolving my problem by spawning a new thread. `var t = new Thread(o => action()); t.Start();`